# Is there a clean way to make Hibernate work with lazy initialization in Swing?

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, lazy-loading

Here is a description of what I want to do in a Swing application.

So, imagine I have an object Client which inside has some collections.
At the application start, I want to load only the object Client and display its basic attributes (like name, age, etc) in a table. At a later time, when the user wants to, I want to load the full Client (the collections).

When I tried to use Hibernate to lazy load the Client, I was getting some problems because of trying to load these objects outside the original session that loaded Client.

I was searching online for a clean/easy way to do this but in the end I ended up doing a hack that I'm not very proud:
Basically I refactored the basic attributes out of the Client and created a class ClientDetails. In the Client I now have a ClientDetails. So at startup I load only ClientDetails and then when necessary I load Client, which will load again a ClientDetails. This will make me have to update the reference of the original ClientDetails that was loaded the first time (this is messy).

So, my question, is there a better/cleaner way to do this by using lazy loading?

Hope this was not too confusing :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should load the `Client` object, close the `Session` that loaded it, and then when you want to display the collection, open another `Session` and *reattach* the `Client` object to it.

Comment: Hi. First of all, thanks for your reply.
Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "reattach the Client object to it"?

Comment: Please see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-overview and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-detached